# Best way to mix bitcoins? mixer, coin join (shared send), dark wallet, stealth addresses?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, privacy, mixing, stealth-address

When you want to anonymize a few hundred BTC, what would be the best (safest) way?

I can think of these alternatives:

- Deposit to and withdraw from exchange (like Kraken, Bitstamp, etc)
  *Pros*: reasonably safe (especially when using a solid, trusted exchange).
  *Cons*: not really anonymous, major exchanges must subject to KYC laws and have strict identification rules.
- Mixing service (like bitmixer.io)
  *Pros*: very anonymous.
  *Cons*: can't really estimate the risk, you have to trust some anonymous 3rd party who can decide to disappear with your coins. Also, it can be expensive (depends on circumstances and requirements, but I'd consider 3 BTC fee to mix 300 BTC kind of expensive).
- Coin Join
  *Pros*: pretty much risk-free (don't have to trust anyone).
  *Cons*: is there a steady, easy, accessible way to setup large coin join transactions? The shared send feature of blockchain.info/wallet? Sharedcoin.com?
- Dark Wallet / Stealth Addresses
  *Pros*: as far as I understand, this offers high anonimity without the need no trust anyone, although I'm not 100% sure of how this works technically.
  *Cons*: To my knowledge it's still in development, unstable, not suitable for usage with large sums of money?

What your take on this? Any other options?

Answer (score 5):

I would say connect to tor, create a blockchain.info account, send you bitcoin there, then send the bitcoin to https://shapeshift.io to another currency which you have a wallet setup, then back to a second blockchain account, then to wherever you want.

This is pretty much 100% untraceable, as it goes via anonymous wallet - anonymouswallet - converted to another blockchain, sent to anonymous wallet, then converted back to bitcoin through another anonymous wallet! You can't track that transaction on the blockchain.

Enjoy :)

Comment: How would one handle the emails needed for the three accounts (2 blockchain.info and one shapeshift)? If I understand https://blockchain.info/wallet/anonymity correctly, they will be able to link my email address to my account. Doesn't this defeat the whole idea?

Comment: @andreas-h, probably, don't use Blockchain.info. Use a local wallet like Electrum or Mycelium and create two accounts. Both wallets allow for connection over Tor and can create multiple accounts. If you need a new email for whatever reason, there are several services which will give free email. I have used Tutanota.com in the past.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this site:

http://silentvault.com/tiki-index.php?page=SBC

It looks like a good option. They're geared toward privacy. Simple mixing of coins is free. They're also based in Panama, which will make it more difficult for anyone from elsewhere to access their records.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate why it "looks like a good option"? Do you have to trust a third party? Do they have sufficient volume?

Answer (score -1):

The source of shared send in blockchain.info is open source. https://github.com/blockchain/Sharedcoin

The limit which blockchain.info offers for shared send is 50BTC. You can check the code and modify the max limit but to mix the coins you should have enough transactions.

check lines 62 and 63 in below code:

https://github.com/blockchain/Sharedcoin/blob/master/website/src/piuk/website/SharedCoin.java

Comment: How does this solution compare to the ones that OP presented? Why does your link solve the asker's question?

Comment: it was an answer to this : is there a steady, easy, accessible way to setup large coin join transactions? The shared send feature of blockchain.info/wallet? Sharedcoin.com?

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should make that more obvious in your answer, as I didn't pick up how answer and question fit together, when I was skimming over them. Also, preferably, answers should respond to the complete question, your answer reads more like a comment on his question than an answer.